# Characterizing the set of solutions to a differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a positive-valued function of two variables, $(x,y)\to f(x,y)$, which satisfies the following inequality

$$f_y\left(1-2\frac{x^2}{f^2y}\right) + \frac{f}{2y} - \frac{x^2}{fy^2} \geq 0 \tag{1}$$

I would like to have an idea of what kind of functions satisfy this inequality. A numerical approach is absolutely fine but even that seems hard. I can solve the differential equation obtained by changing the inequality in $(1)$ to equality numerically for different values of $x$. But then I still don't know in what kind of set the functions satisfying $(1)$ live. I guess I can perturb the obtained numerical solution a bit to see if the perturbed function satisfies $(1)$ but I doubt whether that is a good approach.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at differential inequalities and in particular Chaplygin's theorem.